# Do I need a separate controller for each model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel , and I try to learn best practices.  Do I need to have a separate controller for each model even if I only need a `GET` method, or can I put the method just in basicController?  Also do I need to create a controller for each model and table in my database?

Comment: This is more an opinion-based question. As a recomendation, I'd have a controller even if this has just one method (you could make this controller invokable).

Comment: Yes, have a controller for each individual model. Also follow RESTful routing, i.e GET /users = index, POST /users = store. Also look into using form requests, in there you can handle authorisation and validation outside of the controller and have minimal code within the controller itself

Comment: Kenny Horna thank you for your response, so it doesn't matter if we have lot of controllers in the application?

Comment: jamesphp2 thank you it's very helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a separate `Controller`.  You can return a response right from your routes file:

```php
Route::get('/models', function() {
    return Model::first();
});
```

Replace `Model` and `/models` with whatever's appropriate for your project.

As your project grows, however, most people find it convenient to have a controller for each model, and even separate controllers to handle specific relationships to those models.

Comment: Erich thank you, so as i understand i can return the response just from routes when it's just a GET method

Comment: @abdel.ouam if this answer helped you, you can mark it as the accepted answer.